# import : The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: Pycharm code problem]

```
PS C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject> import scrapy
import : The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: Should we not activate the python shell before running the import statement? Also, I think you should run 'python3 olx_india.py' to check if the import is really working or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the "Terminal" tab, which is neither a "Python Console" (REPL) nor the main editor. Here you use system commands (shell/DOS). Try writing your code elsewhere.

Comment: Any suggestion on where?

Comment: Any file is good. On the screenshot of the OP (top-right quarter) we can see they wrote with their IDE (PyCharm) into the `olx_india.py` file. But the problem is when they wrote in the (bottom half) which is a PowerShell terminal. Either start the `python` program there to enter a REPL, or use the IDE to run the code in the file (green triangle).