# The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: python, powershell, import

```
import : The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ import cv2
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (import:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Where are you entering your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328261/import-the-term-import-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function

Comment: dumping your problem into a stackoverflow question, without any explanation at all, is considered rude. please review [ask] and [mre]. and perhaps take the [tour] if you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to run a Python script as if it were a Windows Powershell script.

Windows Powershell doesn't know what to do with your Python code. That is why it's complaining that `The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Run your Python script using the Python interpreter.

```sh
C:\> python your_script.py
```

And make sure **not** to dump Python code into a running Powershell terminal.

Answer (score -2):

You need to install a wheel file.
Uninstall opencv :

```
py -3.9 -m pip uninstall opencv-python
```

Download the wheel (.whl) file associated with your version of Windows and Python from this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv)

Install this file, for example for 64bit machine with python3.9

```
py -3.9 -m pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp39‑cp39m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Try to import CV2 again, if you still get the error try the following:

```
py -3.9 -m pip install opencv-python
```

Try importing CV2 again and it should work

[remember to replace -3.9 with your version of python, e.g. py -3.10]

Comment: OP's issue has *nothing* to do with OpenCV. that just happened to be the first line of OP's python code, an import, of some module, that happened to be OpenCV, but could have been any other module. the error message clearly says that the `import` keyword was already the issue.